# Best way to spell check a plist?

Tags: iphone, macos, plist, spell-checking

I've got about 400 different NSString entries in my plist file. I want to spell check them. At the moment I'm having to go through, expand each entry (there's a huge amount) and select the text then do a spell check (Cmd + ;).

I really need to spell check the whole thing at once, like you would in a word document, or an excel spreadsheet. I don't mind having to manually filter out the occasional field I don't need changing. It would be quicker that way, than having to go through and select all the different strings separately.

Is there anything I can do? Or am I doing it the best way already?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode, right-click on the file you want to spellcheck. Select "Open as->Plain text file".

From there, you should be able to spellcheck the whole plist.